# IE8 Bootstrap Respond.JS, List Items Not Horizontal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

I am having  problems with the dl-Horizontal class in bootstrap.

I have two columns on my row and within each column I have a dl list.  In all browsers apart from IE 8, the list item () and list value () are next to each other then the next item value pair is on the following row.  However in IE8 the item then value appear under each other and the two columns are under each other.

Thank you for your time.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tomwilliams/hjxct9vo/)

```
 <link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Extern/JQuery/BootStrap/bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Extern/JQuery/Jquerylibs/Jquery1-11/jquery1-11-0.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Extern/JQuery/BootStrap/bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>

     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Extern/JQuery/html5Siv/html5shiv-master/dist/html5shiv.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Extern/JQuery/Respond-master/dest/respond.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->  


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div id="OnlineEstimate" class="OnlineTabCell">
                 <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-5">
                      <dl class="dl-horizontal"> 
                          <dt>Make:</dt><dd><div id="DetMake">aaa</div></dd> 
                          <dt>Model:</dt><dd><div id="DetModel">bbb</div></dd> 
                          <dt>Derivative:</dt><dd><div id="DetDerivative">ccc</div></dd> 
                          <dt>VIN:</dt><dd><div id="DetVin">ddd</div></dd> 
                           <dt>REG:</dt><dd><div id="DetReg">eee</div></dd> 
                          <dt>Colour:</dt><dd><div id="DetMileage">fff</div></dd>
                          <dt>Mileage:</dt><dd><div id="DetColour">ggg</div></dd>
                          <dt>Account:</dt><dd><div id="DetAccount">hhh</div></dd>
                          <dt>Customer No:</dt><dd><div id="DetCustNo">iii</div></dd>
                      </dl> 
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                      <dl class="dl-horizontal"> 
                          <dt>Address:</dt><dd><div id="DetAdd1">aaa</div></dd> 
                          <dt></dt><dd><div id="DetAdd2">bbb</div></dd> 
                          <dt></dt><dd><div id="DetAdd3">ccc</div></dd> 
                          <dt></dt><dd><div id="DetAdd4">ddd</div></dd> 
                           <dt></dt><dd><div id="DetTown">eee</div></dd> 
                          <dt></dt><dd><div id="DetCounty">fff</div></dd>
                          <dt>Postcode:</dt><dd><div id="DetPostcode"></div></dd>

                      </dl> 
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
         </div>
```

The below link is the fiddle full page mode which I was using to test the IE 8 mode!

[Fiddle Full page mode](http://jsfiddle.net/tomwilliams/hjxct9vo/embedded/result/)

regards

Tom

Comment: Please describe what "not working" and "this issue" mean here in your question. We don't all have IE8 available for demonstration purposes.

Comment: If you look at the full page fiddle link in IE, click on developer tools you can drop the version into IE8 mode.  I have two groups, the Make Model group and the address group.  the make / model group should be on the left hand side of the screen, the Address group on the right.  In IE 8 all everything is underneath each other.  so you have Make: then underneath you have aaa followed by Model: etc

Comment: *In the question*, please. You could also make your title more descriptive.

Comment: You don't explain what doesn't work, it's probably the ellipses, that is not supported in IE8, you can use the -ms-text-overflow attribute

Answer (score 0):

Problem was caused by the javascript libraries being placed in the body not the head of the page.